# Linear Transformation (Rotation)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be the rotation by $π/2$ clockwise about the origin, and let $S: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be the shear along the y-axis given by $S(x, y) = (x, x + y)$. (You may assume that these are linear transformations.)

a) Write down, or compute, the standard matrix representations of T and S.

Solution:

[T] = $\begin{bmatrix} cos(π/2)&sin(π/2) \\ -sin(π/2)&cos(π/2)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix}$

$S(1,0) = (1,1) \implies [S(e_1)] = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$S(0,1) = (0,1) \implies [S(e_1)] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\implies [S] = \begin {bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 1&1 \end{bmatrix}$

b) Use (a) to find the standard matrix representations of (i) S ◦ T (T followed by S), and (ii) T ◦ S (S followed by T).

Solution:

i) S ◦ T: $\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 1&1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&1\end{bmatrix}$

ii) T ◦ S: $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 1&1\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix}$

c) Let $C ⊆ \mathbb R^2$ be the unit square whose vertices are $(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)$, and $(1, 1)$.
Draw, on separate axes, the image of C under the transformations (i) S ◦ T and (ii) T ◦ S,
clearly labelling each image. (Please draw large, clear diagrams.)

Can someone please help me with part c? And also check my solution for the first two parts?

Comment: One question per post. Part C asks you to see where the square maps to under the previous two transformations. It suffices to map the vertices.

Comment: @SeanRoberson sorry for being unaware and thank you for helping. So I need to just plot the new points for each transformation and not some complicated drawing showing the actual transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two parts are correct.

The point is that $S \circ T$ and $T \circ S$ are linear transformations.

Therefore, let $(x,y) \in C$. Then from what we know about $C$, we have $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$. Observe that for any linear transformation $L$: 
$$
L(x,y) = xL(1,0) + yL(0,1) 
$$

Therefore, 
$$
L(C) = \{xL(0,1) + yL(1,0) : x,y \in [0,1]\}
$$

From which it is easy to prove that $L(C)$ is the quadrilateral determined by the vertices $L(0,1), L(1,0), L(1,1)$ and $0$.  Calculation of these quantities for $L = S \circ T$ and $L = T \circ S$ gives you the desired conclusions.